# What's the purpose of locking a vote down until the next edit?

Tags: discussion, upvotes, locked-votes

I recently voted up for an answer to a question of mine. Later I found out that the post was just copied from another answer and I wanted to take back my vote. This was not possible because the function to take back the vote is locked until an edit of the post occurs.

What is the purpose of this restriction? Is there any change I can cover the use case I described?

Comment: Well, in the event that the post is plagiarizing content, flag it and link to the content it is plagiarizing; a mod can simply delete the post as a violation of the rules.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the Stack Exchange network (meta.SE).

Comment: @Jefffrey Meta StackExchange actually recommends that most questions, even ones that are network-wide, are asked on child metas first. Then, if it makes sense for them to be moved, the OP can move up to Meta.SE. So while this wouldn't be off-topic at MSE, I don't think it's off-topic here, either.

Comment: @Kevin, And when would it make sense to move them if not when they are SE's related?

Comment: Yeah, @Jefffrey you should really read this: [Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250152/users-can-report-bugs-on-whatever-child-meta-site-suits-them)

Comment: As this might be relevant for metaSE, I did http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230076/whats-the-purpose-of-locking-a-vote-down-until-the-next-edit

Comment: It's one of those [broken-by-design] issues. Introduce a major annoyance to combat a minor problem.

Comment: It would be good if undoing an old vote would be allowed for reputable users. It could be limited to, say, 1 undo per hour (for votes that would normally not be reversible) and/or would *count towards your daily vote limit*, or have a separate daily limit.

Comment: Better yet, don't give people their reputation back for removing their downvote if it would otherwise have been blocked.

Comment: I could live with one undo per week, and a reputation penalty for each undo. My votes represent my best attempt at evaluating the answer at the time I vote. Very rarely, I have second thoughts. For example, a subsequent comment may convince me that my vote was incorrect.

Comment: Possible same on meta.SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80762/why-do-votes-get-locked

Comment: Helps me because I can't see if I have ever voted on a question or answer or not, so I keep hitting it, which lets me know I tried to vote it twice.

Comment: I've VTC'ed the question because the accepted answer is wrong and has proven to be misleading. @Shog9 gave the real reason in the proposed duplicate.

Answer (score 29):

The primary reason is to prevent "tactical downvoting". That is, downvoting the other answers on a question to get yours to rise to the top and, presumably, attract more upvotes. Then, once your answer has enough of a lead, undownvote those other answers to prevent the "hit" on your own reputation.

Some information from an old [post on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70861):

> Basically it's to stop people gaming the system.
>
> One of the ways people did this was by down-voting rival answers and then removing that vote when their answer gains popularity. There are others.
>
> See the following blog entries:
>
> https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/
>
> https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/

See also: [This answer from Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18046).

> To help deal with the "tactical downvoting" problem, we have **radically reduced the window for undoing votes.**
>
> There is now only the very briefest of windows where you can undo a vote. (edit: [this was increased to 5 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23701/why-cant-i-change-my-vote-if-the-post-has-been-edited-during-the-initial-5mn-gr/38759#38759))
>
> After that, the vote is permanently "locked in", until the post is edited. Once the post is edited you may vote for it again.

Comment: Of course when you get enough rep you can just edit the question yourself and then you can change your vote. So it seems like there is a small window when this stops gaming the system.

Comment: Naturally, this doesn't actually do anything to solve the problem it is supposed to solve, since you can still downvote everyone else and make back the rep that you lost by getting upvoted.  All it does is ensure that you can't make things right again later.  If you want to punish people for changing their vote, take away rep for it, don't lock us out from changing our minds.

Comment: Aren't they sorted by "active" nowadays, which doesn't take into account post score?

Comment: @OneKitten They are sorted by Votes, by default. This can be changed by clicking on "Active", "Oldest" or "Votes" at the upper-right corner of the answer content area.

Comment: This doesn’t make the slightest sense. First of all, the message displayed to the user creates confusion as it does not explain anything, not even that the reason is that the voting is too long ago. But more important: *why does the system assume tactical voting on question I have never written an answer for?*.

Comment: @Holger I think that if you are motivated by a high score on SO, then you would create a robot army to go around and upvote your answers and downvote your "competitors". The robot army will never actually answer, just upvote you. Unless that can be detected in which case they will have to behave in a way that remains undetectable. Basically Search Optimization for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Dirk Bester: each robot of that army has to contribute something before it has enough reputation to upvote and it requires even more for downvoting so it’s impossible to create a socket puppet just for tactical voting. Besides that, it has been said by moderators that there are (undisclosed) ways to detect socket puppet voting.

Comment: Shouldn't this needless and harmful feature be teared down?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense for several reasons. First of all, if the only reason to lock votes is to prevent tactical downvoting on _answers_, why lock the vote also on _questions_? Second of all, if the reason is to prevent tactical _downvoting_, why lock _upvotes_? Third of all, why lock voting on comments since comments don't have any effect on reputation?

Comment: the SOLUTION is SIMPLE then: the negative points you get for downvoting an answer (on a question where you also have an answer) should be permanent

Answer (score -7):

I would propose that, 
after someone has voted an answer, besides having an edit window, we have time window as well.

This would be like, you are allowed to revert your vote after a period of say six months of last vote.

This will prevent any serial voting and give users a chance to revert their mistakes.

If they previously had downvoted an answer because of some mistake. They can change it after six months and give author, the rightful reputation he deserves.

Comment: There is a time period in which you're allowed to change your vote. It's just nowhere near *six months* long. Five minutes should be more than long enough for you to realize that you mis-clicked and correct it.

Comment: @CodyGray Mis click is not just what I mean. There are other mistakes. I read an answer. I downvoted it. Then, after few months I realized I was wrong to downvote it, its actually worth an Upvote. Theres no way now I can reverse back my vote. Asking OP to edit his ans/ques for these things, seems absurd.