# Downvoting on meta posts

Tags: discussion, mso-mse-split, downvotes

After the MSO/MSE split there is no reputation system for this meta. So now there is no negative reputation for downvoting on posts?

Previously there was -1 reputation (like on Stack Overflow) for the downvoter. So now there is no reputation change for downvote caster.

[Read the reason here for reference.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251233/821057)

> For Example: User A replies to a popular question with 20 more answer so user downvoted all answers just to make it answer to be at top by votes count. Previously doing this also effect the downvoter by -20 reputation but not now.

So is there any constraint or check to stop not constructive downvotes? Now one can downvote many posts as one wants without affecting reputation.

Comment: You just got one downvote (not from me, btw) so I guess: no, there is not...

Comment: Just like on all other sites, people are free to downvote or upvote for whatever reason they like (except if abusive pattern such as serial voting).

Comment: not constructive downvotes means I down voted 30 other replies on the same question I have posted answer.

Comment: So go ahead and do that. Nothing's stopping you from doing it on the main site either; the 30 imaginary internet points you spend to do it certainly don't have enough marginal utility to affect your decision, do they?

Comment: @Wooble, you have a point, sometimes I feel that fellow SO'ers forget that reputation is just an arbitrary number

Comment: @Wooble coming from 32k users is really amazing! If I have to do something like this I would never post a question to ask for a fix. The point here just is to inform a case that can be happened.

Comment: @SebastianGodelet concern here is not of reputation points but my concern is about this helpful community if there is a case where some people may use it negatively then being a community member we should need to inform and that is what I did here.

Comment: On the old meta, downvoting was actually just used for approval, which is different from quality. I rather like the new system

Comment: The title on this question is very vague, could be improved by making it more descriptive.

Comment: @Cupcake do it plz.

Comment: @SebastianGodelet No, that's not correct.  Downvotes were *not* just for agreement instead of quality.  They were *primarily* based on quality, and only occasionally used to represent agreement.

Answer (score 7):

As was stated in [this post on the Meta Stack Exchange site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228609/is-serial-voting-detection-script-run-for-meta-sites-too), the serial voting script runs on the per-site Metas just as it does on the main sites.

Downvoting competing answers just to make yours look better is of course not nice, but it's not something that's prevented or reversed on any site to the best of my knowledge. Not even those that have reputation.

Comment: serial downvoting runs if someone downvote one particular user, but not if one downvotes different users post where He/She has also posted answer.

Comment: Afaik nothing is done about that on any site.

Comment: all sites have negative reputation on downvotes If I downvote answer of other will cost me -1 reputation. see updated question with details.

Comment: No child-metas have reputation. And they seem to be doing reasonably well. I'm not sure it's a huge problem. They are meta sites anyway, where votes and scores don't matter nearly as much as one could argue they do on regular sites. I don't think this is much of an issue.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed: There is not much incentive to get upvotes in the first place, so I don't think it's something to really worry about.

Comment: ok so now one can downvote 40 votes daily without any reason because votes and score not matters on meta. great :)

Comment: Technically yes @ZaheerAhmed. But until that practically happens, I think you've just found a hypothetical issue and not something that should actually worry us all that much.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed If you were not downvoting low quality posts that you saw on other sites with real reputation just because of the tiny bit of rep it would cost you then *that* is the undesirable behavior.  Losing a tiny bit of rep shouldn't be a reason to not downvote a bad post, especially for someone like you with so much rep already.  Losing a tiny bit just isn't that big of a deal.