# Prevent voting on answers by users who have answers

Tags: feature-request, tactical-downvoting

Here are the requirements of this feature:

1. If a user has already voted on an *answer*, after making her own answer, her vote on that answer no longer counts.
2. If a user has already has his own answer, then he can longer vote on other answers.

The motivation is to make it harder for people to vote strategically. There is precedent in a democracy, in which the candidates cannot vote in their own race. We already have a sportsmanship badge to encourage up votes. This is a good start.

Here are some related posts.

This talks about forcing comments https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281350/why-not-to-force-members-to-leave-comments-when-they-downvote/281351#281351

This talks about using down votes strategically [Six simple tips to get reputation fast on any Stack Exchange site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-reputation-fast-on-any-stack-exchange-site)

This is about voting on the question not on its answers [Require a comment explaining the reason for the first downvote on a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250177/require-a-comment-explaining-the-reason-for-the-first-downvote-on-a-question)

Comment: Wouldn't this idea *kill* the sportsmanship badge? Or are you only talking about downvotes. If you are, I've had answers that were *terrible* pop up after mine. I didn't downvote them strategically, I downvoted them because they were crap.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yes. It would kill the sportsmanship badge and that's a shame. Maybe we could have an additional badge (or stigma) that's awarded to users who down voted 100 answers on questions where an answer of theirs has a positive score.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I would argue that you are down voting appropriately not strategically. Your down vote was based on merit whereas a a strategic one is motivated by jealousy.

Comment: I appreciate that you think that, but your proposal would prevent me from doing so :(

Comment: I almost never DV a competing answer, but I have come back to a question which has an answer I DVed and added an answer in part because the other was so bad.  Would your scheme prevent such an answer?

Comment: @Plutonix Yes. This scheme would prevent such an answer. A user would have a choice: vote on answers or add an answer.

Comment: Well, *anything* that stifles voting on answers is a really bad idea right out of the box.  Look at your stats: ~335k people "reached" for 5800 rep: that means a very very very very small percentage of those "people" (views, page hits, loads whatever) resulted in a vote.

Comment: @Plutonix Based on a lot of the comments, I'm coming to see that my feature request lacks merit. That said, of the ~335k people that I reached, few of those also answered the questions that I answered, so my proposal would stifle only a very small percentage of potential votes.

Comment: But as well, a person might refrain from voting *just in case* they wanted to post an answer.

Comment: @Plutonix This proposal wouldn't prevent that. "If a user has already voted on an answer, after making her own answer, her vote on that answer no longer counts."

Comment: As a meta on the meta, my comments are the only ones that have received zero up votes. I feel confused about that. Have they added nothing useful to the conversation?

Comment: _"Have they added nothing useful to the conversation?"_ Actually, it's more that people have agreed with the other comments and, rather than repeat the same statements, have upvoted said comments to show support.

Comment: Meta votes indicate agreement esp with feature request.  No one UpVoted the Q so they are unlikely to agree with any of the supporting comments

Comment: On Meta.SE: [Block user to vote other answers of the questions when has provided already an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237337)

Comment: *"There is precedent in a democracy, in which the candidates cannot vote in their own race"* - not in the one I live in (UK MPs can vote for themselves, if they're on the electoral roll). Or in others: every election in the US you get the classic *"candidates casting their vote"* clips on the news.

Comment: I agree with this proposition but only for downvoting. There is no reason to prevent anobody from upvoting another answer.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

So if I find a question with a bad answer, I have to choose between downvoting to indicate that to future readers, or leaving an answer that might actually help them?

And if I've answered a question and return to find that someone else has posted an excellent answer outlining an alternate solution, I have to delete my own answer before I can upvote it?

I don't see the advantage here. Nor do I see how your links about requiring comments for voting are *at all* relevant, unless your aim here is to encourage people to answer *in the comments* in which case I think this is an even more harmful idea.

You're misunderstanding the difference between Stack Overflow voting and democratic voting. Stack Overflow voting is more like a straw poll.

Comment: "So if I find a question with a bad answer, I have to choose between downvoting to indicate that to future readers, or leaving an answer that might actually help them?" Yes. This is what candidates in a democratic race do.

Comment: This isn't a democratic "race". It's a Q&A site.

Comment: And if I've answered a question and return to find that someone else has posted an excellent answer outlining an alternate solution, I have to delete my own answer before I can upvote it? Yes. Again, this is the democratic process.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin _"This is what candidates in a democratic race do."_ There's a problem with that: _This isn't a democratic race._ _" Again, this is the democratic process."_ Wrong, on all counts, friend. Votes, up and down, are to _indicate quality._ Nothing else.

Comment: It's a good point that this isn't a democratic race. Is the voting democratic? If not, how could we make it more so?

Comment: The point of all this is to motivate, elevate, and indicate useful answers. Democracy is a system of government; this is more like a straw poll.

Comment: @Shog9 Fair enough. At least I know this is a survey of opinion which is unofficial, casual, or ad hoc not a regulated voting process. I need to accept that.

Answer (score 25):

## No!

Downvoting is still a part of site and content moderation, and while strategic downvoting occurs, I feel like it's more of an edge case than a rampant problem.

Doing this would greatly interfere with a lot of more general voting behaviors rather than isolating the narrow case; what's stopping a user from *drafting* their answer, downvoting everyone strategically, *then* posting it?

Comment: " what's stopping a user from drafting their answer, downvoting everyone strategically, then posting it?" The requirements outline this. After posting, the votes become void.

Comment: If this strategy had been implemented, I wouldn't have been able to upvote this answer. Which would've been a shame, since I think it makes an excellent point about the rarity of strategic voting.

Comment: @Shog9 Yeah. That's a good point too. I think I need to let go of this one, eh.

Comment: The proposal would interfere with a small percentage of voting behaviors by those who are adding answers to the same question. This isn't a lot more general voting behavior.

Comment: I've personally upvoted answers that I thought were spectacular, and downvoted answers I thought were terrible on questions I've answered.  I'd argue that it's a lot more common than you think, especially on a question that is easy to misread but hard to solve.