# Downvoting other answers

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, downvotes, voting

I sometimes get one or multiple downvotes on my positively acclaimed answers without any explanations, which may be due to other answerers trying to get their questions on top.

This obviously shouldn't happen. A possible solution would be to disallow downvoting other users answers, at least until an answer gets picked by the OP or until a certain amount of time passes.

This wouldn't be a perfect solution, if the other answer is low quality, then not being able to downvote it would be bad. This problem can be solved by including downvotes in the review queue (maybe anonymously) or allowing them to vote after the question gets downvoted by a different person.

Comment: How do you know it is other answerers that voted? Adding a new answer puts the question back on the homepage, so there are plenty of new eyes on your answer too. And people that know how to answer a question are often better equipped to judge other answers, so we really would not want to block those from being able to vote.

Comment: This is related [Prevent voting on answers by users who have answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291131/5292302), probably not a duplicate since you have some time feature as well.

Comment: I'm curious if you also like to prevent up-voting during this time?

Comment: Note also there is the [Sportsmanship Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/805/sportsmanship) given when you "up vote 100 answers on questions where an answer of yours has a positive score", in other words, up-vote answers that aren't yours, and it happens to be the badge that I'm most proud of.  Do you have this badge?

Comment: And in fact I've been thinking of creating a feature-request question on meta that would expand on this badge, creating for instance a gold version for folks who do this 1000 times. Why not encourage this behavior through positive reinforcement?

Comment: The problem with that is the OP may not be experienced enough in a subject to judge the quality of an answer, hence we need to prevent him choosing the wrong answer.

Comment: "I sometimes get one or multiple downvotes on my positively acclaimed answers without any explanations, which..." I just figure come from people who think my answer isn't worth that many upvotes or who just don't like me.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes please. A badge like that might be a good idea.

Comment: Never ever ask questions on why down votes, discourage down-votes unless you don't want many down votes :-D

Comment: Is it strange that people have different opinions where some might upvote, some might comment, some might downvote. If I think a question is unclear, or not well researched, I would downvote, even though it might have x upvotes. Same goes for answers, if I believe they are incorrect. I prefer leaving a comment when I think it can be constructive, but I have also seen other way around where I comment first with a remark, and then other people downvote on it (though I was undecided at the time)

Comment: Sometimes I have no idea why some questions are closed or down voted. Here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48164020/why-open-source-redis-cluster-doesnt-support-multiple-databases and I don't know why knowledgeable people are reluctant to share their knowledge but prompt on downvoting.

Answer (score 32):

No, we are *not* going to put votes into a review queue.

Voting is *anonymous and up to the voter*. As long as votes are cast on the contents of the post, and not for whomever wrote the post, they are legitimate and do not need further approval. Only moderators can judge if votes were cast for other reasons (we have more access and can see voting patterns).

Note that when a new answer is added to a question, the question is bumped back up to the homepage, so it'll get *more attention*, and you really can't know who voted on your answer. Please don't make assumptions as to whom voted or why they did so. We certainly wouldn't want to ask others to do the same.

Comment: *OK, fine. I'll flag all down voted answers for mod attention then. Something has to be done!* ...

Answer (score -25):

Yes, there should be done something to do this. My solution is forced to comment(what is the reason for down-vote) when down-voting answer or question.

So they can understand what is their mistake. Yes I know I will have many down-votes for this answer. But I said my opinion :-)

Comment: A forced comment will accomplish nothing but gibberish.

Comment: This has been proposed many times before, and **will not happen**. Comments accompanying are not always well received (see [What can I do in common, to avoid getting "revenge downvotes" for comments / close-, down-votes](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261274)), and *forcing* someone to comment only will lead to gibberish. Voting is anonymous for very good reasons.