# I downvoted an answer, it was deleted and changed, now I can't un-down-vote

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, downvotes

I down-voted an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31092073/basic-php-code-for-inserting-data-into-a-mysql-database/31092095#31092095) question. Not the greatest question, sure, but the answer was still way off. The answer was soon after deleted, and I got my 1 rep point back. I logged on later and saw I had lost the rep point again. I checked the question, and the answerer had re-posted a much better answer. I wanted to fairly rescind my down-vote but I got the "It's been 5 hours, you can't do anything unless the answer is edited" warning.

So, I don't understand why my down-vote seems to have "come back" when the question was re-posted? I am thinking that the user must have un-deleted the question, and then edited it? If that's the case, why can I not take back my downvote?

Comment: There is no edit on any of the two answers ever posted to the question. Did that edit perhaps happen within 5 minutes of the answer being posted, and nobody commented?

Comment: Looking at the revision-history, if there actually was an edit, that'S what must have happened: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31092095/revisions

Comment: I read the question, left my comment for OP, down-voted that answer (it was the only answer at the time), then left a comment to the answerer about why I down-voted. I then left the question and haven't looked back til just a few minutes ago.

Comment: I see that it says deleted and undeleted in the revision history. What does the "5 minute" thing have to with this? I don't understand

Comment: If there's an edit, it will be collapsed with the previous revision (which might be the initial one), iff nobody commented on the post, posted an answer to it, neither is a rollback, it's less than 5 minutes later, and it's by the same user.

Comment: As others have already answered, this is due to edits during the 5 minute grace period, which are not recorded. Editing the post will allow one to change their vote, though arguably, if it deserved a downvote for its original version, perhaps that's not a bad thing ;)

Comment: That again shows the need of a notification when an answer is edited. t could be something like, you downvote/upvote the question/answer and an option appears asking for enabling notifications when an edit is made to the post. 5 min. grace period edits should notify too.

Comment: Alternative to notification would be to give the edit a new revision, even in first 5 minutes, if there is at least one downvote on the answer.

Comment: In the meantime the whole question got deleted.

Comment: @Oded It is *intentional* that people's votes are locked in?  That seems ridiculous.  Isn't this more of a hard to fix bug (not tracking edits in first 5 minutes unintentionally means that fixes in the first 5 minutes don't allow vote reversals as an unintended side effect), rather than a by-design thing, honestly?

Comment: @Yakk [Please search before asking](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291292/3717023).

Comment: @1999 We already have the ability to retract a vote after an edit.  It is just the magical *edit within the 5 minute window* that doesn't allow a vote retract.  It is that **particular** locking that I am questioning if it is intentional.  I suspect the fact that "it is not really an edit" makes the edit vote retraction code not kick in, and this is less of a "by-design" (that would be a strange thing to design) as a "bug that would be hard to fix".  Which is a long winded way of saying what I said in my second sentence above.

Comment: anything with links to `w3schools` should be downvoted to oblivion

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It seems that the author of the answer  deleted it, edited, and undeleted the answer, managing to do all of this within 5 minutes of initial post. Such an edit does not generate a new revision, and therefore does not unlock the votes cast prior to the edit. See [Quick edit not recorded as such blocking vote change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150002/quick-edit-not-recorded-as-such-blocking-vote-change?lq=1).

Comment: Ha, from Jeff Atwood's comment I have gleaned that it is "by design" but still buggy, and that as an SO user I should wait for 5 minutes of posting before downvoting? weird.

Comment: I changed the link (within grace period, heh) so that it points to a newer and better answer. No, you don't have to wait 5 minutes. If your downvote sticks, so be it.

Comment: Heh, yeah, I got there on my own from a link in the first one.

Comment: Anyway, it's a moot point now. The author deleted his answer yet again. There was another answer (pure link-only), but anyway, the question was not worth leaving, so I gave it the final delete-vote.

Comment: Funny how that works out. If I had have stayed away even longer I wouldn't have even known it happened at all. The question was not worth leaving.

Comment: @chiliNUT FWIW grace period would stop and edit would count as new revision, allowing to revert vote if you [commented on that answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289668/839601)

Comment: Worth noting is that the grace period now stops as soon as any comment is posted. If you want, you can provide a comment explaining the downvote, and if the answer is edited, you can then retract the downvote no matter how fast the edit was. (But comments explaining the downvote aren't for everyone: unfortunately, a few posters see such comments as an attack and respond with abuse, either in words or in actions. Don't comment unless you are prepared to deal with that.)

Comment: @1999, Will the problem be solved if he make another edit again after 5 minutes had passed?

Comment: @Pacerier Yes... but it will also be solved if one does nothing. Because there is no real problem to begin with.

Comment: @1999 there was a real problem, if the OP was stuck with casting a downvote that the answer did not merit.  The deletion of the anwer is another way the problem was solved, but the problem was "real".

Comment: @hvd its a shame that some people feel that way, I personally get annoyed when you down-vote and *don't* explain yourself.

Comment: @1999 - This is a site with gamification to encourage certain behaviors. When people find edge cases where the game is broken, even in minor ways, it disrupts the benefits of gamification. Just as people won't continue to play regular games that suffer from glitches, this site suffers (even if a tiny, tiny way) when the game doesn't work as intended.