# Exception to the limits on changing votes has an "abuse" opportunity

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, edits, voting

If I have voted on a post, after some time the vote isn't supposed to be changeable, with 2 exceptions:

1. you may change your vote within a five-minute window
2. you may change your vote after a post is edited

If I — who has earned "edit privileges" — have upvoted a post and the next day change my mind; I'm actually able to do so, as I can myself "edit" the post and then change my own vote.

To change my vote when a post is edited is of course perfectly OK, but to edit a post *myself* so I can undo my own votes? <strike>I think not.</strike>

Comment: This is likely going to be marked [meta-tag:status-by-design]. Its a workaround that leaves a mark in the revision history and is very rarely used (and has been noted and discussed before).

Comment: "I believe everyone needs to stick to their vote, *or at least if one has a good reason not to, has to do it through a moderator.*" No one is going to agree to that. Post contents change...sometimes they improve, sometimes they become worse. Being able to change your vote in response to a change in content is reasonable. Having to go through a mod to do so? Un-scalable, there are only a few mods on SO, and they already have their hands plenty-full with more important things to do.

Comment: @Bob I don't agree with the request, but I think he meant that you shouldn't be able to send an edit YOURSELF just to change your vote. So the "post change" argument can't be used. If the edit is not by the voter, this won't change. I'm still with you that it should not be implemented though

Comment: @Patrice at least, this shouldn't be something that requires a mod to take any action. Preventing users from changing their vote after editing the content themselves is an interesting idea, and I'm not entirely against it (yet). Though I could also make the argument that if I edit something to improve its quality, I should be able to change my vote to an upvote, in reflection of the (now) improved state of the post. I just don't see this as something that could be abused with much effect.

Comment: I consider this a feature. Rarely used, but when you need it, it's great to have.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Could you provide me a link to that/those post where this "has been noted and discussed before"?

Comment: It could only be "abused" if nobody noticed that you edited the post.  That won't work, it is noticeable.  The edit history is readily visible.  You can do this several times before people start seeing the pattern.  They'll warn a moderator, he's put you in a slammer for a week :)

Comment: This is very related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265858/can-we-remove-vote-lock-in/291292#291292

Comment: I'm against this change, as it would mean If i downvoted a post, the author provided clarification in a comment, and i add that clarification back to the question, i wouldn't be able to retract my downvote that was due to lacking clarification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, current behavior is ok.

There are good reasons to change your vote - starting from simple mistake (i.e. "the only Eric Lippert upvote") to actually thinking over the post and finding out that your original opinion is incomplete or totally wrong.

Additionally if you have 2K editing privilege you can wreck much bigger havoc than random +1/-1 vote - as SO stands now people with 2K are trusted enough to make sensible decisions most of the time. Most actions are easily observable by community - so doing strange random edits to strictly change your vote will likely be noted (especially if one does it on recent questions).

There is also enough people running all kind of crazy queries and likely such odd behavior will be found and flagged. So far that problem did not surfaced enough on META and unlikely need any immediate solution.

Comment: Well, when you put it like that I have little to say. "Sometimes you can't see the forest because of all the trees that are in the way".