# Ask question, get answer, up-vote, try it, find out it doesn't work, answer upvotes locked until user edits?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting, locked-votes

So this is probably my fault for upvoting before testing...

But should upvotes and downvotes for answers really be locked for the asker of a question?

I guess from now on I'll test before upvoting.

Comment: A vote means a post is (not) useful. Don't use it as a mean to award effort. That is a disservice to feature visitors. This becomes specially true now you learned that votes are locked after 5 minutes....

Comment: Do note that your accept vote is never locked. You can always change it to another answer or remove it completely.

Comment: Despite the downvotes, hindsight is a good thing.

Comment: @BoltClock yea. pretty used to downvotes on the meta by now.

Comment: Since your talking about it, should vote be NOT locked at all? I can provide an exemple where it was ok to upvote at some point, but then you realize later that you should have not, and not because you haven't tested. The code work, but you realized with further implantation that it can cause problems. But now that you know, it's too late.

Comment: Votes not locking after 5 minutes opens up a lot of avenues for abuse

Comment: This question isn't unclear, it's a Possible duplicate of [Can we remove vote lock-in?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265858/4284627) and [What's the purpose of locking a vote down until the next edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251232/4284627)

Comment: @AntoinePelletier You can provide another example where one voted too early? I don't think that's necessary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Someone decided to provide you the (wrong) answer.  It's your duty to do your due diligence to see if it's correct, accurate or even *applicable* to what you're dealing with.  If it *isn't*, then the only correct vote would be to downvote.

Just upvoting on the spur of the moment can lead to a false signal; leading people to believe that this answer is helpful, when in reality it isn't.

Comment: Ok, but in case you did test the code, and it's working. Your glad, you upvote. Then, later, you realize that, although it work, it's not necessarily a good practice, and it can cause issues when further implemented. You could not know it at the moment you added the code; it's working, but it's bad. Upvote locked on a bad answer, nothing you can do about it. So... ?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier: So, you *did* try the code and it *did* work, but you discover that it's not sustainable later on.    Smells like one failed to due more due diligence.  "Working code" doesn't mean "good code".

Comment: So your telling me i have to wait until i almost reach the end of my life before voting ? Cause you never know, maybe when i'm 80 years old i'll discover that some code wasn't all that great ? Should the possibility to vote in the after life be something implementable ?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier:  If you're 80 and maintaining code you wrote when you were in your mid-twenties, there are several other problems that should arrest your attention besides, "Oh, that code I used from Stack Overflow that one time didn't work out so well."

Comment: Ok, i admit it was a bit exaggerated, more realistic now. I search for an answer, i find it, it work, it looks great. One year later someone write an even better answer to the same question and explain the corner case that forced him to make it better. I'm not going to test every corner case of an answer before voting, it's going to be extremely time consuming. But, if someone else figured it out because he FELT on this corner case. It might not have happened to me yet, but i'm sure going to be preventing it for the futur. Is it better explained ?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier: you can still upvote that late answer. If it is substantially better, it will rise to the top. If it is *crucially* better, someone is bound to edit in a bold capitalized **Do not use the accepted answer!!** (this is not a hyperbole...).

Comment: @usr2564301 That's pretty much a work around instead of a working vote system, was that supposed to be an argument for or against vote lock ?