# Is a trivial edit acceptable if it is to fix an accidental vote?

Tags: discussion, edits, locked-votes

I accidentally down-voted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30685104/1467396) question.  By the time I realized I had done it, it was past the 5 minute grace period and now I cannot take that vote back.

From reading on Meta, I know that the vote lock is intended to prevent "gaming" and "griefing".  These do not apply to my intentions here.

I would like to edit the post so that I can change my vote, but the post is already pretty good.

Under these circumstances, is a trivial edit acceptable so that I can change my vote?

Comment: go re-vote now...

Comment: Thanks for fixing it for me.  I'm still curious what the community's attitude toward this would be...

Comment: It wouldn't be a good practice but if it is just one time then it's not a huge deal and you probably won't be run down by an angry mob with pitchforks. I have found myself in that situation once and I asked the OP to edit and explained why.

Comment: Its a bad habit that almost all of us have.

Comment: The real issue here is that the time limit on retracting votes is harmful and mostly pointless. It heavily wastes the time of people like you who are behaving well in order to supposedly disincentivise badly-behaved others from tactically downvoting competing answers and then retracting the votes to recover their rep. This ignores the fact that 1) the cost is so low that miscreants can still tactically downvote, 2) tactical downvotes don't do much harm anyway, and 3) you could solve the problem both more effectively and without collateral damage by having retracting downvotes not restore rep.

Comment: `in order to supposedly disincentivise badly-behaved others from tactically downvoting competing answers and then retracting the votes to recover their rep.` I'd say  citation needed... I fully agree with the time limit, be it only because people voting should think about what they're doing.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier [citation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251232/whats-the-purpose-of-locking-a-vote-down-until-the-next-edit?rq=1).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As your reputation is below the 2K Free Edit threshold, your well intended "dummy" edit would get placed into the Review Queue and then you'd have to wait for approval.

There is a good chance it gets rejected at that point for a *clearly* Minor Edit - even if you acknowledge this in the description! Sort of the opposite of Robo-Reviewers: reviewers may believe it's just a deliberate hoax to gain *Two Points Of Reputation*! Without the longer back story, there is indeed not much to show your intentions. In the worst case, reviewers may decide you are wasting their Review Quotum and reject just for that. And if the edit got approved you'd gain 2 reputation points for, to be perfectly honest, No Good Reason Whatsoever.

Scan the post and its comments critically. Is there absolutely *nothing* else to improve? Add, remove, or change tags? (... For instance, it is missing a programming language. And I have no idea why the OP thought of [point-of-sale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/point-of-sale).)

If all else fails, post a comment, briefly explain the situation and ask the OP to make a minor change. That way you can change your vote without gaining reputation.

If we *must* declare a Policy for this, it could end up as "it's only one vote, better forget about it"...

Comment: I absolutely agree--users should not bring up individual posts on meta just because they want to change their vote.  My question was simply if I were to make a trivial edit in this case and a reviewer actually read my comment, understood it, and believed me, would my action still be frowned upon?

Comment: @PhatWrat: after some more thinking I clarified my answer. If your trivial edit was accepted *for this reason only*, then you would have gained 2 points **for no visible reason**. (In addition, the question *asker* also gets a net +3 gain, but that's not his fault.) That makes me conclude: don't try to fix it this way.

Comment: "it's only one vote" except when it's the *only vote* on the post, in which case it can make a pretty big difference...

Comment: It's tagged [tag:point-of-sale] because it's about point-of-sale equipment. This is also called POS equipment, and there's a good reason for that. Amazingly, there is even a line of such equipment branded "RealPOS". You have to wonder who came up with that name.

Answer (score 7):

As Jongware indicates because of your rep, an edit would have created a review item and it might be rejected. A post here creates noise and and was not guaranteed to help you either.

On the other hand we are talking about -2 points for the answerer. If you cannot sleep because of that:

- bookmark the question so you can find it (at some point you can come back with enough rep, edit and change your vote).
- look at another posts by the answerer, that you would normally not have looked at, and find one that merits an upvote

If the above still don't let you sleep at night, I think it would have been less noise if you had let the answerer know in a comment that you misvoted but cannot change. The answerer might edit the post as  result of that, or tell you that you are forgiven whether you come back to make the change or not.

Comment: @Jongware Random upvoting is not good, that is why explicitly indicated finding one the merits upvoting. As for the quoting, of course you can, I quoted yours as well didn't I?

Answer (score -3):

As mentioned before a 'dummy' edit is not acceptable.
I believe it shouldn't be allowed to just to change a vote. Because if everybody starts doing this. The reputation system will lose stability and we'll get spammed with old questions at the home page, and a lot of other problems might come up.

To me this brings up an important question though. We're all human, and change our minds quite often. So why wouldn't we with something we voted for here in SO?

I think this could be a great opportunity to change the vote lock system a bit. Because it would affect much of the system if we add a time limit to change a vote.

But back to your question, don't edit something just to change a vote. I would refuse the edit review.

Comment: your third paragraph is confusing to me. If you wanted to change it, wouldn't you want to change it to something it isn't already?

Comment: To change the vote lock system. ;-)

Comment: you mean, a time limit, that would allow you to change your vote after a period of time?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean.

Comment: Think about what that would mean. I would vote on a post, and after 5 minutes, be unable to change my vote. but, then, after another time limit, i would again be allowed to change my vote. isn't that a bit confusing? I was expecting you to suggest removing the vote lock entirely, hence my confusion, :)

Comment: I like the vote lock as it is, as it makes trolling people who complain about getting downvoted more difficult. (downvote, see complaint, remove downvote, see complaint removed, re-add, rinse repeat). It also means you should think about the vote because it can't be changed rather than just voting knowing you can always undo it.

Comment: The vote lock works as a form to stabilise the reputation system. Or it would become quite volatile and mess up what makes SO work. Although I believe that a release for the vote would help fix this issue. Something like a time limit of a week or something like that.