# How to check total Meta Stack Overflow reputation points

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges

Where do my Meta Stack Overflow reputation points get stored? In my profile I can view my Stack Overflow reputation points, but if I view my Meta Stack Overflow profile, the number of questions asked and votes cast are all available, but I cannot see my Meta reputation points. What is my total Meta Stack Overflow reputation points? Does it even exist?

On Stack Overflow, there are badges that are awarded after earning particular reputation points. Do these badges exist on meta and how are they awarded?

Comment: SO and SO meta have the same reputation

Comment: But those 186 reputations behind my name are earned only through SO, am thinking where is the count of [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309564/4361127) reputations

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can see a simulation of the reputation you *would* have if SO Meta actually tracked it by checking [this Virtual Meta Rep query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/215919/virtual-meta-reputation-for-user-x). It doesn't include tag wiki suggestions, the +2 from accepting answers, the -1 penalty from downvoting someone else's answer, the 1-rep floor, or the daily rep cap, so it's not totally accurate, but it's fairly close for most of us.

(For fun, run it on a main site and see how close it gets.)

Comment: After checking this... now I wish there was a way to swap the two.

Comment: @TZHX: I *know*, right?

Comment: It is way off on SO for me.  Like 22% off?

Comment: @Yakk: It says 68144 rather than 67557 when I run it on your profile (SO instead of MSO), which is awfully close. Honestly, though, even 22% is probably not out of reason on some profiles, especially those with lots of bounties earned/offered, lots of suggested edits, tons of downvotes, or lots of daily-rep-capping.

Comment: @nath strange, I got 50k when I ran my own.

Comment: It counts question upvotes as 5, should you update it?

Answer (score 15):

> On Stack Overflow, there are badges that are awarded after earning
>   particular reputation, do these badges exist on meta and how are they
>   awarded?

Yes they do exist.

At the time of writing 4 users have the [Legendary](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/43/legendary) badge on meta for earning 200 daily reputation 150 times and 16 have [Epic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/42/epic) for hitting this 50 times.

There is no official way of seeing this reputation though. Accessing https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation gives the terse message.

> Reputation on this per-site meta is derived entirely from the main
>   site; nothing to show.

Answer (score 8):

There is no *SO Meta reputation*. Questions asked and answered on Meta SO do not earn or lose reputation, so the reputation here is exactly the same as the reputation you have on SO itself. Votes on questions and answers on Meta SO do not affect reputation in any way.

Comment: No, there is MSO reputation (see Martin Smith's answer).

Comment: @ArtjomB.: No, there is no Meta SO reputation. There are Meta SO **badges**, but badges are not **reputation**. The question asked here is *How to check total meta stack overflow reputation?*, and the answer to that is *You can't, because there is no Meta SO **reputation**.*.

Comment: The badges are for earning meta SO reputation. So in some sense it exists.

Comment: @Martin: No, it does not. In fact, you even quoted it yourself in your answer: *Reputation on this per-site meta is derived entirely from the main site; nothing to show.* That sentence **clearly states** there is no Meta SO reputation, and that reputation here is **derived entirely from the main site**. How much more clear can it be stated that there **is no Meta SO reputation**?

Comment: So according to that logic the people that earn legendary on SO should be exactly the same as those that have earned it on meta as if you "Earn 200 daily reputation 150 times." on one site you get it on the meta but *this is not the case*. http://i.stack.imgur.com/ULHlX.png, So there is some internal meta rep calculation.

Comment: @Martin: No. Read what I wrote again: **Badges exist on Meta SO. Reputation does not.** Reputation <> Badges. If that's hard to understand, down (or up) vote a question or answer here at Meta SO (feel free to use this answer to test). Does the poster's reputation change? If you downvoted, was your reputation reduced by doing so? If not, **there is no reputation here at Meta SO**. While those badges may be earned by *votes received*, they are not based on *reputation earned*, because **there is no reputation at Meta SO**.

Comment: The badges aren't based on votes received, Read the description.They are based on **reputation earned** in one day. So I would expect that to include all reputation impacting activity such as upvotes, downvotes, suggested edits, answer acceptances in the usual manner. It just so happens these badges are the only place where these internal rep calculations are exposed.

Comment: @Martin: I suggested a simple test to you that would prove that there is no reputation. Did you try it? **If voting has no impact on your reputation, there is no reputation here.** It doesn't matter how many times you repeat it; it won't change the fact it doesn't exist. If an internal process uses **votes** to award badges, that's not reputation. Reputation is visible in the status bar at the top of the screen (yours currently says 223K), and that's the *only* reputation that exists at SO (and is displayed at Meta SO).

Comment: That is not the *only* type of reputation. As discussed ad nauseum there is another type used in badge calculations.

Comment: @Martin: As you say, as discussed ad nauseum, if a vote on a question or answer does not impact your reputation, it's not reputation. What you're calling *what is used in badge calculations* is simply **votes** and not **reputation**. It's like counting from 1 to 10; it isn't currency simply because it's a number. It's only currency if you can exchange it for goods or services and it's issued by the government. Otherwise, it's just a number.

Answer (score 5):

> How to check total Stack Overflow META reputations?

As Ken notes, meta does not affect reputation in anyway (positively or negatively). Instead, meta reputation is just synced with your SO reputation every so often.

> In Stack Overflow, Badges are awarded ... in META do we have such process?

Yes badges are awarded on meta.  They are earned separately from badges on the main site, so good posts will earn you meta badges.  In a way, badges like ["good answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/24/good-answer) are decent substitutes for MSO "reputation." The other metric that MSO uses is ["participation"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=participation), which is just the sum of activity (votes, comments, posts, edits) on meta.

The over meta [Meta Stack Exchange (MSE)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) does have reputation separate from any other site that follows the normal reputation rules.  Votes, bounties, and the whole nine yards.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to [this excellent answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309623/1079354), if you don't yet have either the Epic or Legendary badges, you can use the badge tracker to give yourself an exact readout of how much reputation on MSO you've earned on a given day.  Things like accepted or unaccepted answers don't count towards the readout.