# Am I allowed to make a 'useless' edit to an answer to unlock my vote

Tags: discussion, voting

From time to time I look back at 'old' votes and I think *hmm, I don't agree with my own vote anymore, let's change that* but I can't because it's locked.

In some cases I've commented asking if the author of the post minds making an edit so I can, in most cases, remove my downvote or change it to an upvote. Sometimes they respond, sometimes they don't. Sometimes they do make the edit but I don't get notified and forget about it, making it all a waste of our time.

It would be a lot easier if I'd just do it myself.

Am I allowed to? Is it frowned upon?

Comment: I admit that I thought this was already the standard (especially with respect to votes on posts by fly-by users)

Comment: Once upon a time I brought this issue up here; back then I was heavily downvoted and my question was closed, I was feeling like I was doing a sin by revoking my upvote by just editing the OP's answer whenever I feel.(Not able to understand this thing now and then).Actually I must be allowed to revoke my vote whenever I feel,But the way I was doing it; was not something valid (in my opinion atleast)

Comment: @znobalG apparently not. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251232/whats-the-purpose-of-locking-a-vote-down-until-the-next-edit

Comment: Editing has side-effects, it reactivates the question.  Whether your mistake is worth pushing a probably less-than-stellar question back to the top and get ahead of questions that *really* should get the attention is rather questionable.  The odds you'll actually tick somebody off in a detectable way are not that great so you'll get away with it.

Comment: @HansPassant I agree. The 'want' to change a vote is not necessarily due to a mistake though. As I learn more, my perspectives change. I might have disagreed with an answer in the past where I don't anymore in the present, and vice-versa.

Comment: @TimCastelijns I agree. I remember once thinking that one person's explanation was bizarre and that they didn't really understand the issue. Later I discovered that it was my own understanding that was lacking.

Comment: Note: The linked duplicate question was asked by a <2k rep user. So, the answers to that question have a different touch than answers to this question by a >2k rep user.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Am I allowed to?

Yes - you have the [edit privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit); we trust you with editing whatever you find appropriate.

It could be helpful if you highlight those things in the answer that changed your mind, for example.

> Is it frowned upon?

The author of the post usually is happy to get 12 reputation points. If he doesn't like your edit, he still can roll it back.

The post will get bumped on the homepage. Usually no one will care, but you still shouldn't do this on mediocre threads that don't deserve any attention.

If you don't have the edit privilege yet, you shouldn't suggest an edit only for the reason of vote changing. This will just clog the review queue. As always, try to make the edit as substantial as possible and fix all mistakes you find.