# How does vote locking work?

Tags: support, voting, grace-period, locked-votes

I often get the message "You last voted X minutes ago. You're vote is now locked unless the Post is edited." Or something similar.

When and how do votes get "locked"?

Is it after a certain amount of time after you vote?

Is it after you changed your vote x times?

Is is a mixture of both or something else entirely?

Basically, at which point does a vote get locked in?

Also interesting to know would be what is the rational behind it?

Comment: It's to prevent "tactical downvoting".  For the why (not the how): [What's the purpose of locking a vote down until the next edit?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251232/whats-the-purpose-of-locking-a-vote-down-until-the-next-edit/251233#251233)

Comment: Thanks :) And do you know how exactly does a vote get locked in? After 5min? after I changed it 4 times already? ...

Comment: @ryanyuyu Seems "griefing" is more important...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After five minutes of casting a vote on an answer or question, the vote gets locked. It will remain locked until the question/answer gets edited.

My assumption on this is that if votes don't get locked, you could un-vote old votes in questions/answers and people would see a lot of reputation drops.

The vote gets unlocked upon editing the answer/question for a simple reason. If you upvote a good answer, and the person that posted the answer edits it and the quality of the edit makes the answer a bad answer, you can decide remove your upvote or cast a downvote instead. Same goes for a bad answer, if it gets edited and the edit makes it a good answer, you can change your downvote to upvote.

Comment: thanks! And suppose I change my vote after 4min, does the countdown start again or will it be locked in in one more minute?

Comment: That's actually a good question. I could not answer it. My guess is that the counter will be reset. But I'm not sure about it.

Comment: And what if you upvote a bad answer, not realizing it's a bad answer at the time?

Comment: I agree with @devios. SO is the site for pros, many answers require additional research to be assessed. 5min is not enough for that. Users should have a chance to contact a mode to revoke their vote anytime.

Comment: I agree with @devios1 too
I have a recent case in which I downvoted an answer as it seemed unhelpful but the author clarified in the comments that the software indeed does what they described. I tried to change my vote and it is locked :( So now there is a valid answer with a incorrect downvote.

Comment: @DBX12 In that situation, I would edit the answer to include the clarification, which would have the side effect of unlocking your vote.

Answer (score 1):

To further answer about the rationale, the fact that it will lock is supposed to make people think twice before they commit to it, whether it's an upvote or a downvote.