# Cancelling accidental down-vote by up-voting loses 1 reputation

Tags: support, reputation, downvotes, upvotes

I clicked accidentally on the down-vote button (while copying text); to correct this, I clicked up-vote but I lost one reputation point.

Is it correct and how do I avoid this?

Comment: Just to note: to correct it you click the downvote button again so you undo your choice. Unless you really do mean to upvote the question/answer of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, if you cancel your downvote on an answer (whether by upvoting it, or by canceling your vote altogether – you can do this by clicking the downvote button again), you gain back the 1 reputation the downvote cost you. Note that you need to do this within 5 minutes; otherwise your vote is ['locked in'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251232/whats-the-purpose-of-locking-a-vote-down-until-the-next-edit) until the post is edited.

<s>You can audit your reputation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4650537/nazark?tab=reputation) and see other possible sources for the reputation loss. There's a checkmark 'show removed posts' which might shed some additional light on the problem. Note that your reputation on Meta is lagging behind a bit.</s>

Comment: i tried to up vote but it says some time restriction, what is this?

Comment: it had happened me two times, while i was looking some posts

Comment: @nazark after five minutes, you're voted is locked. See for more information [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251232/whats-the-purpose-of-locking-a-vote-down-until-the-next-edit).

Comment: so may be i up-voted after 5 mins. thank you,

Comment: I upvote an comment to an answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483497/how-can-i-put-strings-in-an-array-split-by-new-line); After upvoting the comment I upvoted the answer as well. (answer upvotes were 317; after my upvote it changed to incremented to 318.I did this because to be inline with the Stackoverflow recommendation to upvote the question as well as the answer). But the answer was not correct. So i downvoted the answer. this time it change from 318 to 316. I though it would cancel my upvote and changed it to previously state of 317; instead it changed to 316. What should i do ?

Comment: I just want to cancel downvote. So does upvoting would cancel my downvote or pressing upvote button

Comment: @AdeelRazaAzeemi upvoting would cancel your downvote *and* upvote the post, in one step.

Comment: @Glorfindel I tried to upvote but it declined that your last update was less than 23 hours ago and your upvote is locking for (i guess editing)