# Can I have more time to retract up- or downvotes?

Tags: discussion, reputation, downvotes, upvotes

Often I take time to reevaluate the input I have given into stackoverflow. The stackoverflow content improves iteratively.

Regarding up and downvotes, I would like to have more time to retract them from questions or answers that have not been edited.

> You last voted on this question yesterday.
>
> Your vote is now locked in unless this question is edited.

In contrast, I see the benefits of the constraint have been answered: [What's the purpose of locking a vote down until the next edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251232/whats-the-purpose-of-locking-a-vote-down-until-the-next-edit/251233#251233)

Would it be possible to imlpement the constraint in a way that me, the vote-retracting person, does not have a positive benefit by changing the vote, while still giving the person behind the content back the reputation?

Effectively like, changing the number of votes, but keeping the reputation that would result in possible cheating stays untouched.

Comment: Can't speak for those who voted on this Meta question, but the content on Stack Overflow only improves iteratively because it is edited. That action would lift the lock.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the content is *edited*, you can recast your vote. There are limits there, of course, but you can always change your vote on edited content.

If you're coming back 5 minutes later with a change of heart on the content you voted on, take this as a lesson to **be more patient and prudent with your votes**, as you may not get a chance to change them.